# how can i optimize my shortcode function where db is fetched each time shorcode is used in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have recently created a plugin for wordpress.First of all i would like to explain background about what plugin does. The scenario is, csv file is there in some path.Plugin import the csv file into database table once a day.also i have created a shortcode where the data is fetched from previously imported table.function is;

```
function shortcode_mysreView(){
$xcode="";
$column = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = %s AND TABLE_NAME = %s AND COLUMN_NAME = %s ",
    'wordpress',
    $table_name,
    $col_name
));

$finder = " SELECT $col_name from " . $table_name . " WHERE code = " . $xcode;
        $output = $wpdb->get_results($finder);
        $myresult = $output[0]->$col_name;

return check_output($myresult);
}
```

shortcode;

```
add_shortcode('mysre', 'shortcode_mysreView');
```

shortcode used;

```
[mysre name="address"]
```

Now the problem is everytime i use the shorcode somewhere db query is run. I think it's not good practice. Please suggest me a way to perform it in a way that i need not have to touch query everytime shortcode is used.

My thoughts;

- What if i fetch the data once a day when import is performed and store the data as a txt file.
- Is there anything like session or something?

Please suggest me.

Comment: You may want to use Transient API. https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/transients/

Answer (score 0):

Run a crons job that query once a day why not save that day in wp options. And then call get_options when your shortcode is being used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).